# Código em python muito lento?? Acesso a banco de dados Access com pyodbc

Tags: python, banco-de-dados, query, microsoft-access, pyodbc

Preciso obter alguns dados de um banco de dados access enorme (dois, na verdade, dependendo da entrada que eu tiver). Eu tenho uma função que chama esse banco por chunks (se eu tentar um fetchall dá problema de memória). Essa função é chamada algumas vezes pela minha função principal, até eu conseguir obter todos os dados que quero. Vou postar os 2 códigos aqui... preciso conseguir agilizar o tempo de execução...dependendo da entrada isso roda em uns 8 minutos! é muito.

```
def chama_chunk():
    global data
    i=0
    names = [x[0] for x in cursor.description]  #pega os nomes das colunas

    while True: 
        rows = cursor.fetchmany(200) #pega 200 linhas
        if len(rows) == 0: #parar se n tiver nd
            break 
        else: 
            if (i == 0): #se for a 1a linha, cria o dataframe com 200 linhas e colunas conforme em names
                data = pd.DataFrame(np.array(rows),columns=names) 


            else:
                data_append = [{names[i]:x[i] for i in range(len(names))} for x in rows] 
                data_append = pd.DataFrame ( data_append, columns = names) 
                data = pd.concat(objs = [data,data_append], axis = 0) 

            i = i+1 
        if i == 200:
            break
```

a função principal é essa (as colunas sendo deletadas não são necessárias)

```
def faztudo(lista,ponto1,ponto2):
    global ativo
    global reativo
    lista1=lista
    chama_chunk()
    del data['CampoB']
    del data['CampoC']
    del data['Dia']
    del data ['Unidade']
    del data['Ano']
    del data['Consumo']
    del data['Ponto_maxima']
    del data['Demanda_maxima']
    del data['Fator_carga']
    gc.enable()
    ativo=pd.DataFrame(columns=data.columns)
    reativo=pd.DataFrame(columns=data.columns)
    while (data.Mes == mes).any():
        if periodo == "DOM":
            #print("entrou dom")
            data.query('Mes==@mes',inplace=True)
            data.query('Codigo in @lista1',inplace=True)
            data.query('Dia_da_semana=="DM"',inplace=True)
            ativo=ativo.append(data.query('Grandeza==1'))
            reativo=reativo.append(data.query('Grandeza==2'))


        elif periodo == "SAB":
            #print("entrou sab")
            data.query('Mes==@mes',inplace=True)
            data.query('Codigo in @lista1',inplace=True)
            data.query('Dia_da_semana=="SB"',inplace=True)
            ativo=ativo.append(data.query('Grandeza==1'))
            reativo=reativo.append(data.query('Grandeza==2'))

        else:
            #print("entrou resto")
            data.query('Mes==@mes',inplace=True)
            data.query('Codigo in @lista1',inplace=True)
            data.query('Dia_da_semana==@diasuteis',inplace=True)
            ativo=ativo.append(data.query('Grandeza==1'))
            reativo=reativo.append(data.query('Grandeza==2'))


        chama_chunk()
        del data['CampoB']
        del data['CampoC']
        del data['Dia']
        del data ['Unidade']
        del data['Ano']
        del data['Consumo']
        del data['Ponto_maxima']
        del data['Demanda_maxima']
        del data['Fator_carga']
```

e a minha query é feita pela função inicia:

```
def inicia (dbpath,mes):
    #dbpath="W:\\CuCa-2018-ZFA.mdb"
    driver='{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}'
    con = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={}; DBQ={}".format(driver,dbpath))
    query="SELECT * from Curvas_de_carga"
    global cursor
    cursor = con.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
```

alguns outros pedaços de código não foram citados, mas creio que o problema de desempenho está praticamente nessas 3 funções.

Sou iniciante em acessos a banco de dados :/ 
E a opção de trocar de banco de dados não existe aqui, pois o banco não é meu, estou acessando um arquivo de outra pessoa.

Answer (score 0):

É muito provável que o tempo que demore seja da querry

```
query="SELECT * from Curvas_de_carga"
```

Tenta restringir mais a procura de querry usando o "where", como por exemplo usando uma data para limitar a procura (entre dia x a y, ou de x até hoje)

Mas experimenta fazer só para testar:

```
query="SELECT * from Curvas_de_carga" LIMIT 100;
```

Vais obter "poucos" resultados mas se for mais rápido é porque andas a fazer uma procura muito grande.

Answer (score 0):

Teste o seguinte:
evite inserir essa etapa parece que você não faz nada com essas colunas (não faz comparação ou coisa do tipo)

```
del data['CampoB']
del data['CampoC']
del data['Dia']
del data ['Unidade']
del data['Ano']
del data['Consumo']
del data['Ponto_maxima']
del data['Demanda_maxima']
del data['Fator_carga']
```

Veja se excluindo essas colunas da consulta (antes de trazer para o dataframe isso pode acelerar sua consulta pois você está trazendo menos dados e provavelmente ai você consegue subir a quantidade de registros (passar de 200 por loop)